# How to compile all the libraries as static but one as shared?

Tags: cmake

My folder structure is like that:

```
├── SubLibA
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── SubLibA.h
│   └── SubLibA.cpp
├── SubLibB
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── structs.h
│   └── SubLibB.cpp
└── SharedLib
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── SharedLib.h
    ├── SharedLib.cpp
    └── SharedLib.h
```

My global `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
add_subdirectory(SubLibA)
add_subdirectory(SubLibB)
add_subdirectory(SharedLib)
```

They all compile as static by default.

- `SharedLib` depends on `SubLibB` that depends on `SubLibA`.
- The dependent libraries `SharedLib` and `SubLibB` have:

```
#SubLibB
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    SubLibA::SubLibA
)

#SharedLib
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    SubLibB::SubLibB
)
```

Running `cmake .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` compiles all the three libs as shared library...

Since they are tightly dependent, I'd like to keep them in the same repository with a unique CMakeLists.txt that compiles them all at once. I want to use the power of Modern CMake with the least hard-coded file and custom files as possible to keep a straightforward maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the variable within cmake:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
add_subdirectory(SubLibA)
add_subdirectory(SubLibB)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
add_subdirectory(SharedLib)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
```

Comment: "Note that cached variables have priority over variables set within scripts" - That is not true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `SubLibA` and `SubLibB` always be static libraries you can use the `STATIC` keyword on the `add_library` command, e.g. `add_library(SubLibA STATIC ${SOURCES})` By omitting the keyword for `SharedLib` you are still free to build it as static or shared lib by setting `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` on the CMake command line.